# asgiref AsyncToSync explanation

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels

```
# https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/master/asgiref/sync.py
class AsyncToSync:
    """
    Utility class which turns an awaitable that only works on the thread with
    the event loop into a synchronous callable that works in a subthread.

    If the call stack contains an async loop, the code runs there.
    Otherwise, the code runs in a new loop in a new thread.
    
    ###############  DON'T UNDERSTAND ####################
    Either way, this thread then pauses and waits to run any thread_sensitive
    code called from further down the call stack using SyncToAsync, before
    finally exiting once the async task returns.
    """
```

Can anyone help to explain the bolded text? thanks in advance!